# Handling of device insertion and removal on Embedded Linux

Tags: linux, qt, embedded

I have an application for the USB interface in QT (Embedded linux).

When Pendrive inserted kernel sends a signal for that and i want to recognize that signal and want my QT application to detect it.

I went through the unix signal handling tutorial of QT but i could not find any way of my problem.

I implemented the same thing as done in the tutorial but i did not find the way to detect the pendrive. It only kills the processes.

Please go through the following link.

[QT Unix Signal Handling](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/unix-signals.html)

I have also found using QdBus library of qt. I cross compiled it but gave me the errors of lidbus version.

Is there any other way to detect the external pendrive from the application ?

Comment: You might want to check out [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/), especially it's [hotplug event handling](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0.16/group__hotplug.html).

Comment: The kernel is most definitely *not* sending unix signals to applications upon device insertion/removal! A unix signal is a very specific way of doing asynchronous calling withing a process. You don't need to worry about unix signals nor about dbus. Joachim points in the right direction: you need to handle hotplug events.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is broadcasting [**netlink**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) information.  You can,

- write a custom `QSocket()` to get **netlink** information. See: [Qt Projects thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/7714)
- write *socket* code directly to get the **netlink** info
- use an off the shelf toolkit like `libusb`, which will use **netlink**.
- add a script to *udev.conf* or *mdev.conf* to write a file and use [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qfilesystemwatcher.html); possibly */etc/fstab* as well.  `udev` and `mdev` are the standard *hotplug* handlers and they have configuration files that allow you to run a script on an event.  The underlying mechanism is again **netlink**.

Parsing **netlink** or using */etc/fstab* maybe better if you want to *automount* the file system.  If you choose the parsing route, you need to parse [the `name=value` information](https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt)<sup>Search for `netlink`</sup>, which is quite easy.

Comment: See: [Why and How to Use Netlink Socket](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356) and maybe [Manipulating the Networking Environment Using RTNETLINK](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8498) from the *Linux Journal*.  There are probably many other tutorials available; *libusb* is possible, but unless you want to directly manipulate a **USB** device, it seems to be excessive.  To simply get notification for *mass storage*, I think one of the other mechanisms will achieve the same results more efficiently.  Also, I don't think *fstab* allows the execution of scripts after looking a little.

Comment: I got the solution i Have used the busybox facility of mkdev.conf. In which i have added the support for the USB pendrive detection and used the udev utility to make the bridge between the linux and Application signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution i Have used the busybox facility of mkdev.conf. In which i have added the support for the USB pendrive detection and used the udev utility to make the bridge between the linux and Application signal handler.